# Copy charts from Excel to PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

I have a slide deck that changes it's name daily. The source data is in several statically named Excel 2013 worksheets. It would be neater to run a macro from the PPTM but all the examples I have found for copying charts is from the XLSM side.
Is there a PowerPoint 2013 equivalent of `PowerPoint.Application`? `Dim sourceXL As excel.Application` gives *Run-time error '424': Oject required* as Excel is not recognised whereas .Application is.

Comment: There is an `Application` object in PowerPoint. How are you using it that causes the error?

Comment: There is a PowerPoint.Application object in PowerPoint and an Excel.Application object in Excel but no Excel.Application in PowerPoint or PowerPoint.Appication object in Excel.

Comment: But from Excel you can refer to the PowerPoint.Application and vice versa. You can set a reference to the PowerPoint object model in your Excel VB Project. You use 'Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application` to declare a variable that references a PowerPoint instance. You use `Set pptApp = CreateObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")` to open PowerPoint from Excel and assign the variable to that PowerPoint instance.

Comment: So if you share the code that produces the error, someone might be able to help.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the line `Dim sourceXL As excel.Application` and also that I have Office 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set a reference to Excel? In the VBE, go to the Tools menu > References, scroll down to Microsoft Excel, and check the box.

Comment: No; I had not. I was unaware of that requirement. Thank you Jon.